# Patch Command Not Working, Creating the Record in the Existing Item

Tags: powerapp, update, patching, submit

I have an application which have 3 leave types to select for the leave request,I am using a form control but submitting the data using the Patch Function.
I am showing the form fields according to the leave request selected in the dropdown in my form.

and on submit button I have set this Code:

```
   If(DataCardValue1.Selected.Value = "Time Off",
Patch(
   LeaveRequests,
   {
       ID:LeaveGallery.Selected.ID
       
    
   },
{
   LeaveID: CurrentUserID,    
   User:     DataCardValue6.Text,
   Requestor: MyUserEmail,
   Approver:
   {
 Claims: Concatenate(
          "i:0#.f|membership|",
          DataCardValue3.Selected.Email // Person email
          ),
          Department: "",
          DisplayName: "",
          Email: DataCardValue3.Selected.Email, // Person email
          JobTitle: "",
          Picture: ""
},
 Description: DataCardValue2.Text,
   TimeOffDate: DataCardValue22.SelectedDate,
   TimeOffFrom: DataCardValue19.Selected,
   TimeOffTo: DataCardValue20.Selected,
   TotalTimeRequested: Label23.Text,
   LeaveStatus:"Pending"
    }
  ),DataCardValue1.Selected.Value = "Annual Leave",
Patch(
   LeaveRequests,
   {
       ID:LeaveGallery.Selected.ID
       
    
   },
{
   LeaveID: CurrentUserID,    
   User:     DataCardValue6.Text,
 Requestor: MyUserEmail,
   Approver:
   {
 Claims: Concatenate(
          "i:0#.f|membership|",
          DataCardValue3.Selected.Email // Person email
          ),
          Department: "",
          DisplayName: "",
          Email: DataCardValue3.Selected.Email, // Person email
          JobTitle: "",
          Picture: ""
},
 Description: DataCardValue2.Text,
   StartDate:StartDate.SelectedDate,
   EndDate:EndDate.SelectedDate,
   DaysCount:Label25.Text,
   LeaveStatus:"Pending"
    }
),
DataCardValue1.Selected.Value = "Sick Leave",
Patch(
   LeaveRequests,
   {
       ID:LeaveGallery.Selected.ID
       
    
   },
{
   LeaveID: CurrentUserID,    
   User:     DataCardValue6.Text,
 Requestor: MyUserEmail,
   Approver:
   {
 Claims: Concatenate(
          "i:0#.f|membership|",
          DataCardValue3.Selected.Email // Person email
          ),
          Department: "",
          DisplayName: "",
          Email: DataCardValue3.Selected.Email, // Person email
          JobTitle: "",
          Picture: ""
},
 Description: DataCardValue2.Text,
   StartDate:StartDate.SelectedDate,
   EndDate:EndDate.SelectedDate,
   DaysCount:Label25.Text,
   LeaveStatus:"Pending"
    }
),
DataCardValue1.Selected.Value = "Casual Leave",
Patch(
   LeaveRequests,
   {
       ID:LeaveGallery.Selected.ID
       
    
   },
{
   LeaveID: CurrentUserID,    
   User:     DataCardValue6.Text,
   Requestor: MyUserEmail,
   Approver:
   {
 Claims: Concatenate(
          "i:0#.f|membership|",
          DataCardValue3.Selected.Email // Person email
          ),
          Department: "",
          DisplayName: "",
          Email: DataCardValue3.Selected.Email, // Person email
          JobTitle: "",
          Picture: ""
},
 Description: DataCardValue2.Text,
   StartDate:StartDate.SelectedDate,
   EndDate:EndDate.SelectedDate,
   DaysCount:Label25.Text,
   LeaveStatus:"Pending"
    }
)
);
 Navigate(SucessScreen,None);
```

after submitting it stores the data into SP list, but when I create another record it overwrites onto the existing one, without creating a new record.

any help?

Answer (score 0):

In your patch code, you are using {ID:LeaveGallery.Selected.ID}, and that means you are patching that specific record in the **LeaveRequests** Datasource (SharePoint list in your case I believe).

For the patch to create a new record, you need to use the Defaults() function. So it would be:

```
Patch(LeaveRequests, Defaults(LeaveRequests), {//your patching code here}).
```

One thing I like to do is to have a single Patch function that handles both "Insert" and "Update" methods. So you can use something like this:

```
If(IsUpdate, Set(varItemToBePatched, LookUp(LeaveRequests, ID = LeaveGallery.Selected.ID),Set(varItemToBePatched, Defaults(LeaveRequests))));
Patch(LeaveRequests,varItemToBePatched,{//your patching code here})
```

Another tip, instead of having all the patches for each "DataCardValue1.Selected.Value", put that "if" inside your patch as well, so you have a single patch function to change/maintain:

```
Patch(
LeaveRequests,
{
   ID:LeaveGallery.Selected.ID
   

},
{
LeaveID: CurrentUserID,    
User:     DataCardValue6.Text,
Requestor: MyUserEmail,
Approver:
{
Claims: Concatenate(
      "i:0#.f|membership|",
      DataCardValue3.Selected.Email // Person email
      ),
      Department: "",
      DisplayName: "",
      Email: DataCardValue3.Selected.Email, // Person email
      JobTitle: "",
      Picture: ""
},
Description: DataCardValue2.Text,
TimeOffDate: DataCardValue22.SelectedDate,
TimeOffFrom: DataCardValue19.Selected,
TimeOffTo: DataCardValue20.Selected,
TotalTimeRequested: Label23.Text,
YourColumn:If(DataCardValue1.Selected.Value = "Time Off","something",DataCardValue1.Selected.Value = "Casual Leave","something else")
}
)
```

Hope it helps